# Downloading list of PDF file from URL

Tags: python, list, pdf, url, download

From the first website, I gathered a list of unique identifiers. The unique identifiers define the website URL where the PDF file is located. In total, it is a list of more than 400 files.

I would like to build a for-loop t iterate over the list of URL's. However, I keep recieving error's which I cannot solve. Could someone explain the error I'm making?

```
# Import van pakketten python
import os
import pandas as pd
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

# Defineren van bestandslocaties
map_archive = r'C:\folder\\'
map_huidig_boekjaar = r'C:\folder\\'

# Download gemeentecodes
if not os.path.exists(r'C:\folder\Gemeenten alfabetisch 2022.xlsx'):
    url_gemeentecodes = 'https://www.cbs.nl/-/media/cbs/onze-diensten/methoden/classificaties/overig/gemeenten-alfabetisch-2022.xlsx'

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"download.default_directory": map_archive}
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
    driver.get(url_gemeentecodes)
    sleep(2)
    driver.quit()

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\folder\Gemeenten alfabetisch 2022.xlsx', dtype='str')
print(df.head())

# Defineren locatie bestanden huidig boekjaar
bron_url_1 = "https://findo.nl/jaarstukken/Jaarstukken_2018_GEMEENTE18_"
bron_url_2 = ".pdf"

Jaarrekening_url_2021 = bron_url_1 + df["Gemeentecode"].astype(str) + bron_url_2
Jaarrekening_url_2021.to_csv('url_list.txt', index=False, header=False, sep=",")
Bestand_naam = map_huidig_boekjaar + df["Gemeentecode"].astype(str) + bron_url_2

# Download bestanden 2021
def download_pdf(url, filename):

    # Send GET request
    response = requests.get(url)

    # Save the PDF
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(response.content)
    else:
        print(response.status_code, filename)

for url in Jaarrekening_url_2021 :
   download(Jaarrekening_url_2021, Jaarrekening_url_2021)
```

The error message that I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\meind\SynologyDrive\6. Python projecten\SiSa\Jaarrekeningen gemeente downloaden.py", line 52, in <module>
    download_pdf(Jaarrekening_url_2021, Jaarrekening_url_2021)
  File "C:\Users\meind\SynologyDrive\6. Python projecten\SiSa\Jaarrekeningen gemeente downloaden.py", line 43, in download_pdf
    response = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\meind\SynologyDrive\6. Python projecten\SiSa\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\meind\SynologyDrive\6. Python projecten\SiSa\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\meind\SynologyDrive\6. Python projecten\SiSa\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\meind\SynologyDrive\6. Python projecten\SiSa\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 695, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Users\meind\SynologyDrive\6. Python projecten\SiSa\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 792, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}")
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '0      https://findo.nl/jaarstukken/Jaarstukken_2018_...\n1      https://findo.nl/jaarstukken/Jaarstukken_2018_...\n2      https://findo.nl/jaarstukken/Jaarstukken_2018_...\n3      https://findo.nl/jaarstukken/Jaarstukken_2018_...\n4      https://findo.nl/jaarstukken/Jaarstukken_2018_...\n                             ...                        \n340    https://findo.nl/jaarstukken/Jaarstukken_2018_...\n341    https://findo.nl/jaarstukken/Jaarstukken_2018_...\n342    https://findo.nl/jaarstukken/Jaarstukken_2018_...\n343    https://findo.nl/jaarstukken/Jaarstukken_2018_...\n344    https://findo.nl/jaarstukken/Jaarstukken_2018_...\nName: Gemeentecode, Length: 345, dtype: object'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please include the errors and tracebacks you're getting in your post.

Comment: Why not downloading everything using selenium, as you already use it ?

Comment: Included the error messages this time around

Comment: Don't use selenium because I don't know how to use it in the second case. When there is a pop-up with download request selenium is fine. However with the second link I get a PDF opened in the browser (chrome). When it opens in Chrome, I don't know how to use selenium to get the file